# Why does internet communication work between two clients?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

NOTE: my terminology and understanding is most likely incorrect, please educate me!

**TL;DR**

Why can't I connect from one client to another over the internet without port forwarding?
How is this different from any website / internet-based software which connects two clients together?

**What I have read**

- [It's impossible to connect to a known IP without port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204773/connecting-to-a-known-external-ip-and-internal-ip-without-port-forwarding)

> Two solutions - the simplest is a port forwarding rule on his firewall, the second is as you suggest an external server that both clients connect to.

- [Connecting between computers in Python](https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/how-to-control-a-device-through-the-network/)

> Accessing a computer from outside the local network is possible, but it normally depends on the policy of the institution where you work. The easiest way is to have port forwarding...

**My understanding**

A router protects all the client computer fs from outside connections (e.g. firewall). And this prevents two clients from connecting over the internet even if they know each other's IP addresses unless you explicitly tell your router to let them communicate by something like port forwarding.

I have always thought that websites are just servers running on a computer somewhere. But apparently this isn't correct, since we just established that a server running on a computer cannot connect to another computer over the internet because firewall.

- I (client) can open up a browser, go to a web domain (external IP server), and download a picture.
- But I (server) can't write a program to send a picture to an external IP (client).
- I also (client) can't write a program to connect to an external IP (server) and download a picture from it.

**Questions (looks like a lot but it's repetitive)**

How is an external server that a client connects to (which has an external IP and is accepted through the router's firewall) any different from an external server that a client connects to (which has an external IP but is not accepted through the router's firewall)?

Essentially what is the difference between my computer running a server and a web domain server (computer).

What is different about the ISP, router, firewall of a web domain server from my own computer.

What is the difference between a computer I rent online running my server program which anybody in the world can connect to and my own computer running my server program which nobody can connect to (outside my LAN).

Why is it impossible for my own computer to run a server which anybody can connect to. What is the difference between a central server and a server on a computer in my LAN?

Comment: "I also (client) can't write a program to connect to an external IP (server) and download a picture from it." - Yes you can? Why can't you?

Comment: You have run into the NAPT variant of NAT that is a kludge to extend the life of IPv4. It breaks to IP end-to-end paradigm, where every interface gets a unique IP address. IPv4 simply does not have enough addresses to do that (it was a government/academic _experiment_ that did not foresee the current Internet). IPv6 has enough addresses to restore the IP end-to-end paradigm. You will still run into firewalls that could prevent you from connecting to anything you want using IPv6, and you would need to coordinate with the target to open a firewall rule to allow you in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think that your confusion is based around what we can do on the internet `vs` what a typical internet user's configuration and package are.

Before I go further, I am not going to answer your questions assuming *typical* IPv4 options, not IPv6.

When we talk about public server IPs we really mean  **static, owned external IP addresses**. These are IP addresses that do not change and are controlled by an organization. That is why they often have a domain name associated with them via DNS. All the traffic sent on the internet to that address comes into their equipment (rented or otherwise). So they can choose to allow/dissallow traffic to get to a server that will actually do something with the data.

> What is different about the ISP, router, firewall of a web domain server from my own computer.

Your internet is through a dynamic, NAT'd (possibly [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)'d), public IP address. Periodically your public address will change. This is cheaper to implement and it assumes you just want to make connections outbound (Get website, not host website). You have to explicitly tell it to change its behavior when you want it to listen on a port.

> What is the difference between a computer I rent online running my server program which anybody in the world can connect to and my own computer running my server program which nobody can connect to (outside my LAN).

It has a static public IP.

> Why is it impossible for my own computer to run a server which anybody can connect to

That's not true. As you mentioned, if your carrier allows port forwarding you can open up a port to the internet. You also can use more advanced tactics like [Nat-punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)).

**Closing Note**
Asking your internet provider for the cost of a static IP plan (don't need to buy it) is a great way to see how they offer the true *sever* external IP.

Also IPv6 tries to make it so NATs are optional and anyone can host anything. Carrier's have just been very slow to adopt it.

Comment: "_Carrier's have just been very slow to adopt it._" Less so than you may think. See the _[Google IPv6 Statistics](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html)_ page. There is a tab where you can check per country. For example, Google IPv6 traffic is over 45% in the U.S.

Comment: @RonMaupin I mean IPv6 World Launch Day was over 10 years ago. I had the sticker and was full of hope. 33% is great to see but I just feel technologies like CGNAT allowed carriers to bandaid the address exhaustion problem and greatly slow down adoption.

Comment: @RonMaupin to my knowledge there are two classes of carriers: those which *primarily* use IPv6 (mostly for mobile phones) and those where it doesn't really work at all. Like scientific theories, uptake of IPv6 is mostly driven by the uptake of a new class of device (mobile phones) and not by home connections switching over. The transition will be complete when home internet dies out.

Comment: The major U.S. ISPs all support IPv6, including for residential Internet connections. Some people are using IPv6 at home without even knowing it. The big problem is the slow business adoption of IPv6 is lagging (witness Stack Exchange lagging in this), not the residential IPv6 adoption. I find it ironic that technical web sites are behind in IPv6 adoption, while I see many non-technical sites use it. I could disable IPv4 on my home network if Stack Exchange would add it because all the other sites I use have it. You can get a browser plugin to see this.

Answer (score 0):

On your home network you have a home router. This home router uses a technique called NAT which breaks your Internet connection and then duct-tapes it mostly back together again. It does this because otherwise there aren't enough IP addresses for everyone to have one.

NAT intercepts connections from your computer, phone, etc. and makes them look like they came from the home router, instead. Everything outside of your network thinks your network is one computer (which is the router) with one IP address (the router's IP address). As far as the Internet can tell, your computer doesn't exist, nor does your phone, your laptop or your tablet.

You cannot make a connection to your computer from the Internet because your computer doesn't actually have an IP address on the Internet. Oh sure, your computer *thinks* it does - one of those 192.168 thingies - but that's basically just a game of pretend between the NAT router and your computer.

People outside the network can only connect to the router, because that's the only IP address that really exists on the Internet. So if you want to run a server, they have to connect to the router, and you have to tell the router what to do with that connection. This is port forwarding. Otherwise, the router has no way to know what to do with the connection request.

In an ideal world your desktop computer would just have an IP address, and if you wanted to connect to your desktop computer, you'd connect to the IP address of your desktop computer, and that would be that. This is how it was before the IP address shortage. And this is also how it is today with IPv6, where there's no shortage. If you don't have IPv6, ask your ISP. If your ISP doesn't support IPv6, their service is terrible and you should use a different one.

---

When you rent a server they do not put their rented-out servers behind NAT routers, because they would be useless. Every server you can rent has its own IP address.

Your ISP might also have a NAT router, because there aren't even enough IP addresses for every *house* to get one. Double the NAT, double the breakage. And your ISP *won't* set up port forwarding on theirs. In this case, they might be able to give you your own IP address (connect your router to the Internet) if you ask nicely and pay them a bunch of money. You'd still want to use NAT on your router because otherwise you'd pay a lot more money for a lot more IP addresses.